# How to convert date from format 14/Dec/2012 14:53:34 to timestamp in php?

Tags: php, timestamp, strftime, strptime

I tried many ways to do, but string format for month makes me big problem. Any suggestion, advice or realised code will be helpfull.

Comment: Where are you retrieving the data from? Is it an SQL result?

Answer (score 6):

strtotime(); doesn't appear to work for that format.

Have a look at using a DateTime object using your custom format: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Then you can output it however you'd like, including timestamp via $dateObject->format('U');

So something like:

```
$oDt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y H:i:s', '14/Dec/2012 14:53:34');
echo $oDt->format('U'); // 1355518414
```

Should work.

Verify backwards:

```
echo date('c', 1355518414); //2012-12-14T14:53:34-06:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried strtotime()? Complete documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.3+ then you can get a `DateTime` using `DateTime::createFromFormat('j/M/Y H:i:s',$string)` then you can use `getTimestamp()` on the returned `DateTime` object to get the timestamp.